# when i click on button for opening popup in angular it add some extra space at the end to the component where i want to open popup?

Tags: javascript, angular

for popup i made a function through which i want to open it and that function pass to button .call that 
function when 
click 
on button

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private login: LoginComponent) {

   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }


//  //this function is used to popup the login page
  openDialog(): void {

   const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

       dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
       dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, dialogConfig);
 }

}
this is button code from where i want to open popup
<button type="button" (click)="openDialog()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin-modal">Sign In</button>
```

this work fine to open popup but it extra space to component where i want to open it.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: @ng-suhas did you tell me what is stackblitz .because i dont know about it and also not used ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ is a site where you can create a demo of your application, suc h that it would be easy to solve your issue :)

Comment: @ng-suhas thanks .. but i didn't this.

Comment: @ng-suhas i created account on stackblitz.